# Using maps to count strings input

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to count repeated words using a map if the user inputs the string once the output will be "OK" else the output will be the string and the number of the Repetition time of the string next to it

I know the code looks very dumb, It's my first time using maps and I'm not familiar with the syntax

any help will be appreciated

```
int main()
{
    int t, i = 0;
    string s;
    map<string, int> m;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        cin >> s;
        m[s] = i++;
        if (i == 0)
            cout << "OK";
        else
            cout << m[s] << m.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Be careful, you're incrementing `i` in each iteration of your while loop. So every string you enter after the first one will be considered as duplicate (assuming `t` > 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    cin >> s;
    m[s]++;
    if (m[s] == 1)
        cout << "OK\n";
    else
        cout << "this is the " << m[s] << "th occurence of " << s << "\n";
```

Note that you can use `m[s]` even if `s` is not yet in the map, because the operator `[]` will add it automatically and initialize its second to zero.

EDIT: to avoid the search in the map twice (see comment of @Slava), we can do better in this way (faster):

```
    cin >> s;
    i = ++m[s];
    if (i == 1)
        cout << "OK\n";
    else
        cout << "this is the " << i << "th occurence of " << s << "\n";
```

Comment: Though this code would work it hides the fact that it is unnecessary doing expensive operation twice or even three times.

Comment: @Slava true, added a second version to do the search only once.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful